# Ios 8 Widget not showing body

Tags: swift, widget, ios8, ios-app-extension

I am creating a Bitcoin price ticker app, with a Notification Center widget that will show the price. When I create the widget, though, no matter what I put in the body in interface builder, it doesn't show. When I look at the widget in notification center, I just see the title, and not the body.

The title shows up just fine, and the widget can be added and removed from Notification Center, suggesting the phone understands that the widget is present. Here's what's been done: 
1. Setting "perferredContentSize" programmatically to the size I want.
2. Adding

```
init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder!) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)

}
```

to the project.

3. Restarting the iPhone
4. Re-building the app in Xcode to ensure no data is corrupt.

I've found several similar questions about this issue, but they all say to comment out the supplied init method. Apple must have removed this, as the viewcontroller.swift file does not seem to have the referenced method.

What should I do? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I hope you mean iOS 8, because iOS 7 does not support Notification Center widgets.

Comment: @astroCB yes! Sorry!

Comment: No problem: I just wanted to clarify.

Comment: I have found it does not show the body when there is some error in the code or the widget storyboard. Post some of the TodayViewController code if this doesn't help